# How to run a specific version of the app from Git via Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, version-control

I use git as my VCS and commit my code every few days. However, a bug has crept in and I need to check if the previously committed versions of the app had that bug too.

How do I keep switching the current codebase to different git versions without losing the local changes that I have not committed? **Is there a way in Android Studio to directly build and test a specific version from the git?**

Answer (score 0):

Some may suggest `git stash` and `git stash pop/apply`.

```
git stash
git checkout <commit>
# build and test
git checkout <previous-branch>
git stash pop
# or git stash apply
```

But I recommend `git worktree`. Suppose the version is `abc123`:

```
git worktree add /path/to/foo abc123
cd /path/to/foo
# build and test
```

The folders and files of `abc123` are checked out into `/path/to/foo`. It does not affect the current main working tree. When the job is done in `/path/to/foo`, you can just remove the extra working tree by:

```
git worktree remove /path/to/foo
# or
rm -rf /path/to/foo
git worktree prune
```